# Problems presenting View Controller from UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm working with local notifications in iOS for the first time, and I was wondering how to push to a specific view from the notification that is not the default ViewController on launch. From looking at other questions I have the code

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:gameViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

gameViewController is the name of the file of the ViewController I want to push (it is not in a Navigation controller). The error I receive is "Use of undeclared identifier 'gameViewController'. I realize this is because it is not declared in the appDelegate, but how do I do so? When I declared it as a property the code compiled, but crashed when I pressed on the notification. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare the class and a property in appdelegate.h see code below:

```
#import "gameViewController.h"
@class gameViewController;

 @interface XAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate >

@property (nonatomic, strong) gameViewController *gameVC;
```

then in your app delegate.m  - synthesise the property

```
  @synthesize gameVC;
    .....

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

 {       
...  
 gameVC= [[gameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"gameViewController" bundle:nil];
 ....
}


  -(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

 [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:gameVC animated:NO completion:nil];

app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;



 }
```

Most people including myself use UIAlertviews instead of modal views for local notification but the code above should work as well (saves the effort of creating a separate VC).

Comment: Where do you initialise the reference to gameVC - You need to set the property somewhere.

Comment: Yes it needs to be initialized in didfinishlaunching with options - let me correct the edit.